# Test date logic in korn shell

Tags: shell

I am looking for a way to test the following korn shell date logic for different days and times. I do not have root access to change the actual date on the system.

```
CUR_DAY=$(TZ="US/Eastern" date +%a)
typeset -i CUR_HOUR=$(TZ="US/Eastern" date +%H)

# Set the start and end hour given in eastern time
typeset -i START_HOUR=22
typeset -i END_HOUR=7

case $CUR_DAY in
    Sun)
      if [[ $CUR_HOUR -ge $START_HOUR ]]
      then
         echo "Send message1"
      fi;;
   Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu)
      if [[ $CUR_HOUR -ge $START_HOUR || $CUR_HOUR -lt $END_HOUR ]]
      then
         echo "Send message2"
      fi;;
   Fri)
      if [[ "$CUR_HOUR" -lt $END_HOUR ]]
      then
         echo "Send message3"
      fi;;
esac
```

Comment: Which version? ksh93? ksh88? A clone such as mksh? Can you rely on having GNU date available?

Comment: BTW, all-caps names for your own variables are bad form -- that namespace is reserved for variables special to the system or shell; see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment and shell variables share a namespace.

Comment: Your Mon-Thu logic should be `start <= cur && cur < end` -- what you have now is: *any* hour is ok: hour 23 is >= 7 and hour 3 is < 22

Comment: @glenn jackman I think my logic is correct. The statement is true between 10pm and 7am. So for 2pm, 14 is not greater than 22 nor is 14 less than 7 therefore the statement is false.

Comment: Ah. It was not clear that you were *ex*cluding 7:00am to 10pm

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to test this is to conditionally add the `-d` argument to `date` (assuming the GNU implementation) to pass it a specific date and time for which you intend to test the function's behavior.

The below passes arguments straight through to `date`, allowing the invocation to be adapted as appropriate:

```
check_dates() {
    typeset cur_day cur_hour start_hour end_hour

    # call external date command only once to minimize external process overhead
    read -r cur_day cur_hour < <(TZ="US/Eastern" date "$@" +'%a %H')

    # trim leading 0s -- otherwise, values will be seen as octal when performing math
    cur_day=${cur_day#0}; cur_hour=${cur_hour#0}

    start_hour=22
    end_hour=8

    case $cur_day in
        Sun)
            if (( cur_hour <= start_hour )); then
                echo "Send message1"
            fi
            ;;
        Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu)
            if (( cur_hour >= start_hour )) || (( cur_hour < end_hour )); then
                echo "Send message2"
            fi
            ;;
        Fri)
            if (( cur_hour < end_hour )); then
                echo "Send message3"
            fi
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Thereafter:

```
check_dates                              # check for current date and time
check_dates -d '2015-01-06 03:00:00 UTC' # check for a specific date and time
```

---

If you're inclined not to use `"$@"`, and don't mind hardcoding behavior specific to GNU date, consider:

```
check_dates() {
  typeset cur_day cur_hour for_date
  for_date=$1

  read -r cur_day cur_hour < <(TZ="US/Eastern" date ${for_date:+ -d "$for_date"} +'%a %H')
  ...
}
```

...which passes `-d "$for_date"` only if `for_date` is set to a non-empty value.

Comment: ksh (ksh93 anyway) does not seem to have a problem with invalid octal numbers: `(( 09 >= 7 )) && echo ok`

Comment: Good to know. I'm still inclined to leave that in for portability's sake, as with it present this code works with bash as well.

Comment: Right. Note that the cur_day will not have any zeroes in it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I only provided a code snippet. The actual function already has other arguments so the $@ will not work.

Comment: @KenStein, you can always shift the others off. `foo=$1; shift; bar=$1; shift;` -- and then you have `"$@"` with the rest.

Comment: @KenStein, ...also see prior versions of my answer, which didn't depend on `$@`, in the edit history; v3 in particular was tested to work.

Comment: @KenStein, ...I've edited in an addendum with equivalent behavior to the v3 version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test just the logic (and not that `date` is working correctly), then allow your script to accept `CUR_DAY` and `CUR_HOUR` as arguments or via the environment, instead of always running `date`.

Via the environment (`CUR_DAY=9 CUR_HOUR=22 myscript`)

```
: ${CUR_DAY:=$(date +%a)}
: ${CUR_HOUR:=$(date +%H)}
```

Via arguments (`myscript 9 22`)

```
CUR_DAY=${1:-$(date +%a)}
CUR_HOUR=${2:-$(date +%H)}
```

Either approach will work in any POSIX-compliant shell.

Comment: Heh. I actually started out that way, then changed my mind and backed out. (First rev of my answer had some vestiges of it left behind, using `${1:-...}` for cur_day but not cur_hour).

Comment: ...arguably, testing the behavior of `date` is important: If I hadn't backtracked and made that decision, I wouldn't have picked up the compatibilty issue with shells that treat values starting with 0s as octal.

Comment: `date` is an external dependency, so you need to test that differently anyway. If you take depedency injection to the extreme, you don't even hard-code the `date` command; you make the name of the (external) command that provides a date an argument to your script.

Comment: What about aliasing date to 'date -d "20160201 03:00:00"' ?
If so, how can I get the script to see the alias?